# How to fetch data that is not similar

Tags: mysql, group-by, where

I have this table:

```
| id | user_id | status |
|  a |       1 |      p |
|  a |       1 |      p |
|  a |       1 |     np |
|  a |       1 |     pp |
|  b |       2 |     np |
|  b |       2 |     np |
|  c |       3 |     pp |
|  c |       3 |      p |
|  d |       4 |      p |
|  d |       4 |      p |
```

I want to fetch those records who don't have the same status records with group by user_id:

```
| id | user_id |
|  a |       1 |
|  c |       3 |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `GROUP BY` both `id` and `user_id` and only keep records `HAVNG` more than 1 `distinct status`.

#### Query:

```
SELECT id
    , user_id
    , count(distinct status)
FROM data
GROUP BY Id, user_id
HAVING count(distinct status) > 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d62a4d/6/0)

#### Output:

```
| id | user_id | count(distinct status) |
|----|---------|------------------------|
|  a |       1 |                      3 |
|  c |       3 |                      2 |
```